# When using flask-restplus, how do I marshal a json which is a simple list (with no attribute)?

Tags: python-3.x, list, marshalling, flask-restplus

I am developing an API using flask-restplus. One of my endpoint returns a list of object, e.g.

```
[
  {
    "id": "1342",
    "index": "meta",
    "score": 3.0630198
  },
  {
    "id": "1645",
    "index": "meta",
    "score": 3.0630198
  },
  {
    "id": "2345",
    "index": "meta",
    "score": 3.0630198
  }
]
```

Now I am trying to develop a model using fields so I can marshal it as a result of get, e.g

```
model = namespace.model('MyModel', {
    "some_attribute":fields.List(fields.Nested(some_nested_object))
})

@namespace.route('')
class FlashcardAutocompleteAPI(Resource):
...
   @namespace.marshal_with(model,code=200)
   def get(self):
      ...
```

The above code of course works, but does not marshal the correct structure.

Is there any way to NOT declare the "some_attribute" part, such that the model would marshal the json structure as provided above? Trying this:

```
 model = namespace.model('MyModel', {
    fields.List(fields.Nested(some_nested_object))
})
```

I receive:

```
  TypeError: cannot convert dictionary update sequence element #0 to a 
  sequence
```

Comment: I have the same issue with `flask-restx` and a simle `bool` parameter, which is a valid json

Answer (score 2):

not sure if this helps, I had a similar problem but with the `post` method instead of `get`. In this case I had the `expect` decorator before the method

```
@ns.expect(model, validate=True)
```

and it worked if I just wrap the model with brackets, like so:

```
@ns.expect([model] validate=True)
```

The solution was pointed out in https://github.com/noirbizarre/flask-restplus/issues/230

I know this is just a partial answer, but maybe sheds some light on the issue. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to declare a new model, flask-restplus can reuse the same model described by `some_nested_object` to marshall either a single item or a list of items of that type.

So you just need to write something like this:

```
@namespace.route('')
class FlashcardAutocompleteAPI(Resource):
...
   @namespace.marshal_with(some_nested_object,code=200)
   def get(self):
      items = build_object_list()
      return items
```